# marking duplicates in a csv file

Tags: python, csv, duplicates

I'm stumped with a problem illustrated in the sample below:

```
"ID","NAME","PHONE","REF","DISCARD"
1,"JOHN",12345,,
2,"PETER",6232,,
3,"JON",12345,,
4,"PETERSON",6232,,
5,"ALEX",7854,,
6,"JON",12345,,
```

I want to detect duplicates in column "PHONE", and mark the subsequent duplicates using the column "REF", with a value pointing to the "ID" of the first item and the value "Yes" for the "DISCARD" column

```
"ID","NAME","PHONE","REF","DISCARD"
1,"JOHN",12345,1,
2,"PETER",6232,2,
3,"JON",12345,1,"Yes"
4,"PETERSON",6232,2,"Yes"
5,"ALEX",7854,,
6,"JON",12345,1,"Yes"
```

So, how do I go about it?
I tried this code but my logic wasn't right, of course.

```
import csv
myfile = open("C:\Users\Eduardo\Documents\TEST2.csv", "rb")
myfile1 = open("C:\Users\Eduardo\Documents\TEST2.csv", "rb")

dest = csv.writer(open("C:\Users\Eduardo\Documents\TESTFIXED.csv", "wb"), dialect="excel")

reader = csv.reader(myfile)
verum = list(reader)
verum.sort(key=lambda x: x[2])
for i, row in enumerate(verum):
    if row[2] == verum[i][2]:
        verum[i][3] = row[0]

print verum
```

Your direction and help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You appear to relying on exact match to determine if two phone numbers are duplicates. This is usual only in the classroom. In the real world, the same phone number could be written 12345678, 1234-5678, 1234 5678, (555) 1234-5678, +1-555-1234-5678 etc etc in the USA/Canada/etc phone system ... in other areas leading zeroes get inserted  e.g. +61-412-345-678 and (0412) 345-678 are the same mobile aka "cell" phone in Australia. Also multiple people can share the same non-mobile phone number; are you sure that you shouldn't be checking the name before you discard?

Comment: The example is oversimplified for my need here. The data has gone through some cleansing and normalization and all phone data is within the country. I'll explain the real case:

I had our customer's (company's) database in an Excel spreadsheet. Then I inserted a whole bunch of entries from Yellow Pages. In the past when a duplicate was found, we simply eliminated that row. But now I am trying to using references and a flag "discard" especially to deal with entries that are a bit similar. I first was doing that manually and it would take me too long for around 6000 entries!

Comment: After testing phone first and analysing the results, I intend to use difflib.SequenceMatcher for the address field. It has worked pretty good in my test cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only thing you have to keep in memory while this is running is a map of phone numbers to their IDs.

```
map = {}
with open(r'c:\temp\input.csv', 'r') as fin:
    reader = csv.reader(fin)
    with open(r'c:\temp\output.csv', 'w') as fout:
        writer = csv.writer(fout)
        # omit this if the file has no header row
        writer.writerow(next(reader))
        for row in reader:
            (id, name, phone, ref, discard) = row
            if map.has_key(phone):
                ref = map[phone]
                discard = "YES"
            else:
                map[phone] = id
            writer.writerow((id, name, phone, ref, discard))
```

Comment: +1 A very clear and practical solution: doesn't use obfuscatory sophistry (dict.setdefault and itertools.groupby) and uses names instead of numbers for columns.

Comment: Yes, setdefault does make mine a little less clear.  I was attempting to be as efficient as possible, but that's likely not necessary here.

Comment: Your 'with' statements will possibly cause the files to close while a reader or writer is still attached to them.

Comment: When the scope of the second 'with' is over, fout will be closed.  But someone could still call writer.writerow().

Comment: @omnifarious: you should have kept quiet and not risked my reading your answer again :-)

Comment: That's hardly an issue unique to `with` blocks.  If you didn't use a `with` block, and closed `fout` explicitly, it would be just as possible for someone to call `writer.writerow()` and discover that the underlying file object was closed.

Comment: In my case I would change 'w' to 'wb' to avoid a blank line between each row.

Comment: That's a platform-specific issue; on Windows either setting produces the same result.

Comment: @Robert Rossney: for correct operation on any platform, the 'b' flag should be used for both csv readers and csv writers in Python 2.x -- and Windows is the OS where the same behaviour is NOT guaranteed if you leave out the 'b'.

Comment: I know I've needed to use the 'b' setting in the past on Windows.  But I wonder why changing the setting doesn't appear to produce different results when I test this specific code.

Comment: @Robert Rossney: "doesn't appear to" != "doesn't". Don't wonder, debug! What happens when you use 'w' for mode instead of 'wb' on Windows is that every `\n` in the file is preceded by a spurious `\r`. Use something like `repr(open('x.csv', 'rb').read())` to see exactly what you have in the file with each mode option. Note that csv is in effect a BINARY format which uses `\r\n` as a platform-independent row terminator, and quotes `\r` and `\n` when they appear as part of the data. You don't want Windows to delete `\r` on input and insert it on output. You should use 'b' unconditionally.

Comment: @Robert Rossney, the answer is to not close the file, or make sure the csv reader and writer are closed and no longer using the file before closing it.  If you are going to use `with` blocks, you should've had them clean up the csv reader and writer first, the files second.

Comment: Could you possibly point me to an example?  The documentation for the csv module gives no indication that it's even *possible* to close a reader or writer.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like homework. Since this is a CSV file (and thus changing the record size is next to impossible) you are best off loading the whole file into memory and manipulating it there before writing it out to a new file. Create a list of strings which is the original lines of the file. Then create a map, insert into the the phone number (the key) and the value (the id). Before the insert you look for the number if it already exists, you update the line containing the duplicate phone number. If it isn't already in the map, you insert the (phone, id) pair.

Comment: Yes it does sound like one, but it is not. Real work on real job in a non-programmers work environment. I just simplified the code to focus on a way to express my problem. And I was glad to find out using dicts is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

import csv
verum = csv.reader(open('data.csv','rb'))

verum.sort(key=itemgetter(2,0))
def grouper( verum ):
    for key, grp in groupby(verum,itemgetter(2)):
        # key = phone number, grp = records with that number
        first = grp.next()
        # first item gets its id written into the 4th column
        yield [first[0],first[1],first[2],first[0],''] #or list(itemgetter(0,1,2,0,4)(first)) 
        for x in grp:
            # all others get the first items id as ref
            yield [x[0],x[1],x[2], first[0], "Yes"]

for line in sorted(grouper(verum), key=itemgetter(0)):
    print line
```

Outputs:

```
['1', 'JOHN', '12345', '1', '']
['2', 'PETER', '6232', '2', '']
['3', 'JON', '12345', '1', 'Yes']
['4', 'PETERSON', '6232', '2', 'Yes']
['5', 'ALEX', '7854', '5', '']
['6', 'JON', '12345', '1', 'Yes']
```

Writing the data back is left to the reader ;-)

Comment: I definitely need to learn more about itertools.grouby. But I still don't understand it well.

Answer (score 0):

I know one thing.  I know you don't have to read the entire file into memory to accomplish this.

```
import csv
myfile = "C:\Users\Eduardo\Documents\TEST2.csv"

dest = csv.writer(open("C:\Users\Eduardo\Documents\TESTFIXED.csv", "wb"), dialect="excel")

phonedict = {}

for row in cvs.reader(open(myfile, "r")):
    # setdefault sets the value to the second argument if it hasn't been set, and then
    # returns what the value in the dictionary is.
    firstid = phonedict.setdefault(row[2], row[0])
    row[3] = firstid
    if firstid is not row[0]:
       row[4] = "Yes"
    dest.writerow(row)
```

Comment: -1 ... reasons (1) using dict.setdefault (which needs explanation) (2) using subscripts instead of meaningful column names (3) using `is not` instead of '!=' (which requires a careful reader to analyse the code to ensure that it works) (4) not using `r` prefix on string constants that are filenames containing backslashes (5) setting row[3] unconditionally instead of only when there's a duplicate (as specified by the OP).

Comment: Thanks Omnifarious, for being the first to answer and pointing me to a solution using a dictionary. Also for even correcting your first attempt to help me.

Comment: @John Machin, The OP is wrong on the last point.  The output clearly shows that the id column is set unconditionally.

Answer (score 0):

I work with large 40k plus record csv files, the easiest way to get rid of dupes it with Access.
1. Create new database, 
2, Tables tab    Get external Data
3. Save Table.
4. Queries tab    New find dupe wizard ( Match on phone field, show all fields and count)
5. Save Query ( export has .txt but name dupes.txt )
6. Import Query result as new table, do not import field with dupe count..
7. Query    Find unmatched (match by phone field, show all fields in result. save query then Export has .txt but name unique.txt)
8. Import unique file in to existing table ( dupes ) 
9.You can now save and export again into what ever files type you need and not have any dupes